# Imported table from datapump utility is of less size and have fewer rows than it was exported?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump, impdp

I have a data dump file which was created through `EXPDP` utility in oracle 11g. The log file of export is as:

```
;;; 
Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Oct 30 19:00:03 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
FLASHBACK automatically enabled to preserve database integrity.
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_51":  system/******** DIRECTORY=BKPDIR DUMPFILE=expfull-Friday-19.dmp FULL=Y LOGFILE=expfull-Friday-19.log exclude=table:"in ('HSTT_DAILY_OPBL_DTL_28/04/18')" reuse_dumpfiles=y compression=all 
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 427.6 GB
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/PROFILE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYS_USER/USER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/USER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/ROLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT/PROC_SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/GRANT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/RESOURCE_COST
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/DB_LINK
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TRUSTED_DB_LINK
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SEQUENCE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/DIRECTORY
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/DIRECTORY/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/CONTEXT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PUBLIC_SYNONYM/SYNONYM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/SYNONYM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TYPE/TYPE_SPEC
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TYPE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PRE_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PROCOBJ
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/POST_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/PRE_TABLE_ACTION
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/AUDIT_OBJ
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/FUNCTION/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/COMMENT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PACKAGE_BODIES/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TYPE/TYPE_BODY
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/POST_TABLE_ACTION
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/VIEW/TRIGGER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/EVENT/TRIGGER
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/MATERIALIZED_VIEW
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/MATERIALIZED_VIEW_LOG
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/JOB
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/POST_INSTANCE/PROCACT_INSTANCE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/POST_INSTANCE/PROCDEPOBJ
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/POST_SCHEMA/PROCOBJ
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/POST_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/AUDIT
. . exported "DWH"."HSTT_PATEMP_ISSUE_ITEM_DTL"          18.55 GB 571100903 rows
. . exported "DWH"."HSTT_PATEMP_ISSUE_DTL"               8.385 GB 179526012 rows
. . exported "DWH"."HSTT_PATEMP_ISSUE_ITEM_17_18"        5.255 GB 167873686 rows
. . exported "DWH"."HRGT_PATIENT_DTL"                    3.854 GB 129233803 rows
. . exported "DWH"."HSTT_PATEMP_ISSUE_DTL_17_18"         2.319 GB 53207892 rows
```

I tried to import the data in oracle 12c using `IMPDP` utility. But some of the imported tables are of a lesser size and has fewer rows then the exported one. The log file of the import of one of such table: `"DWH"."HRGT_PATIENT_DTL"` is as follows:

```
  C:\Users\User>IMPDP parfile=E:\Jaipur_Restore\jaipur.par

Import: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Nov 11 18:32:00 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: / AS SYSDBA

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options
Master table "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01":  /******** AS SYSDBA parfile=E:\Jaipur_Restore\jaipur.par
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "DWH"."HRGT_PATIENT_DTL"                    2.766 GB 93314254 rows
Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at Wed Nov 11 18:36:56 2020 elapsed 0 00:04:50
```

The parameter file used during import is as follows:

```
directory=jaipur
logfile=IMPORT.LOG
dumpfile=EXPDAT01.DMP
EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT
EXCLUDE=TRIGGER
EXCLUDE=INDEX
EXCLUDE=OBJECT_GRANT
EXCLUDE=INDEX_STATISTICS
EXCLUDE=USER
EXCLUDE=ROLE
EXCLUDE=SYNONYM
EXCLUDE=PROFILE
EXCLUDE=TABLESPACE
EXCLUDE=GRANT
EXCLUDE=PROCACT_SYSTEM
EXCLUDE=TYPE
EXCLUDE=SEQUENCE
EXCLUDE=DIRECTORY
EXCLUDE=CONTEXT




TRANSFORM=oid:n

remap_tablespace=HIS_USER:JAIPUR
remap_tablespace=USERS02:JAIPUR
remap_tablespace=HFMS:JAIPUR
remap_tablespace=EPAY:JAIPUR
remap_tablespace=TBS_FOR_INDEX:JAIPUR
remap_tablespace=TEMP_TEST:JAIPUR
remap_tablespace=TEMP01:JAIPUR
 
table_exists_action=replace
```

**What is the reason for the difference in the size of the imported table and how it can be resolved?**

Comment: Are you sure you're importing from the right file? The export is to `expfull-Friday-19.dmp`, the import is from `EXPDAT01.DMP`. You could have just renamed it of course, maybe when moving it from `BKPDIR` to `jaipur` if those are different OS directories underneath. But I suspect it just isn't the file you expect.

Comment: Why are you running it as SYSDBA.  The docs _very specifically_ say not to do that: "Do not start Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users."  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-D5455260-C28C-475F-9E0E-2BE227E7F0E3

Comment: @AlexPoole yes you are right, indeed! thanks!